# Update class member before access in C++

Tags: c++, class, member

I'd like to ask if by **only using operator overloading** is there a way to update a class member before accessing it.
For example, I've got this class

```
class DictionaryWord
{
    string      Word;
    unsigned    Size;
    unsigned    Score;
};
```

and I want whenever I do `objDictionaryWord->Size` to get `Word.size()`

P.S. Also, I'm just starting to learn C++, if you know of some excelent tutorials for beginners that explain operator overloading please share them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ member "Word" will change from time to time (let's say I'm going to make it public and change it directly). Right now I'm poking around the language and I want to know what's it capable of, so I'm really interested only in operator overloading (and hope that by seeing some code written by C++ gurus I'll be able to better understand this concept)

Comment: Write a function to do that: `unsigned Size() { return word.size(); }`

Comment: There's no way with operator overloading.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm only interested in doing it with operator overloading. I wouldn't have asked if I wanted it otherwise. So far I've learned that "." (member access operator isn't overloadable, but "->" and "->*" are, yet I'm having issues overloading them - don't know where to start)

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Also, is there a way to know to which member is the -> operator pointing to?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, thanks for chatting with me :)